# iOS touch reporting frequency

Tags: ios

I have a custom UISlider subclass that is intended to restrict the rate at which the slider can move.  Ideally, I would like this restriction to be in a verbally sensible manner such as "5 units per second".  Right now the best I have been able to do is restrict the amount the slider's value can change on a per-update basis.  I could theoretically track the time since the last update was triggered, but if the user doesn't move his/her finger for a short time, then that calculation goes out the window.

In short: is there a way I can get the touch event frequency of the device, so that in the event that the touch events are slower on one device or the other, the rate of change with respect to real time remains constant?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you monitoring the touch start and end, to see when a touch began?

Then before the touch end, see the amount the X axis of the touch event changed and depending on the movement move the slider accordingly ?

What you need is use these 3 delegate methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

You can have a boolean that marks the start/end of the touches and then if the boolean is true you can use the touchesMoved delegate to move the slider.

Comment: Do these begin,action,end messages get sent for every single touch event?  The majority of the action being taken by the slider happens on touch move events

Comment: I have edited the answer. It should give you an idea of what you need to do to implement this.

Comment: I'm not sure how what youre suggesting is different from the normal slider behavior

Comment: You could move the slider to whatever pixels you want depending on how much the user has moved his finger on the screen, which would result controlling the slider movement, which is what you want if I understood correctly.

Comment: That is exactly what my current subclass of UISlider does, but that movement restriction is frame-based, not time-based.  Like I said in the question, I would like the adjustment to be limited to something like "5 units per second" instead of "5 units per frame"

Comment: What do you want to measure then? You need to explain better what you mean by "touch event frequency".

Comment: The system reports touch events (began, moved, ended) at a certain frequency, knowing that frequency, or the time between given touch events, I could turn my "units per frame" measure into a "units per second measure".  I cannot simply track the time myself, because there may be times at which no touch events are reported because the user has not moved his or her finger at all for some time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11699/discussion-between-lefteris-and-dan-f)